# How to convert plot3 matlab file to Obj file?

Tags: matlab, object, 3d, matlab-figure

I would like to convert plot3 graph generated in MATLAB to obj file so that it can be imported into 3D max .
How it can be done ?

There is a code for mesh here but how it is done for plot3. I want to import  just lines that can be edited in 3D max.
http://www.aleph.se/Nada/Ray/matlabobj.html#4

I would like to change the color of each individual line after import or to write it to obj file.

Comment: OBJ file means something else entirely in programming parlance.  You maybe should edit your title to say "to 3D Studio Max file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `write_wobj` function, which is used to convert fig files into obj. The functions code is already given on the link
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27982-wavefront-obj-toolbox/content/write_wobj.m